# find start offset of 2 audio files

Tags: audio, sync

I have 2 audio files that overlap significantly (recorded with seperate devices).

The image shows my 2 files and as you can see they recorded the same thing but one started almost 15 mins earlier.
Is there a way with python, ffprobe or similar to get exact starting offset?
I want to sync them up exactly (automatically not manually).

[image: my 2 audio files opened in audacity]

Comment: You could have lined it up sample-perfect by eye in the time it took you to write this question ;) As it was recorded on two separate devices you may have to compensate for slip through the track anyway.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes I could have done that but I know that I will have this problem more than once in the next week. I really want to automate it.